# Can't access foreign key property in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two classes - `pop_vlans` and `logical_interfaces` defined as follows:

**logical_interface.rb**

```
class LogicalInterface < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pop_vlans
end
```

**pop_vlans.rb**

```
class PopVlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'pop_vlans'
  belongs_to :logical_interface, :class_name => "LogicalInterface", :foreign_key => "vlan_id"
end
```

Then in my controller I am trying to access the `pop_id` column of the related `pop_vlans` object but I get an undefined error:

**logical_interface_controller.rb**

```
def update
  if params[:id]
    @logical_interface = LogicalInterface.find(params[:id]) 

     @pop_id = @logical_interface.pop_vlan.pop_id # error
  end
end
```

However, I can get the property I want but it requires a few extra lines:

```
@vlan_id = @logical_interface.vlan_id

@pop_vlan = PopVlan.find(@vlan_id) 

@pop_id = @pop_vlan.pop_id
```

but I'd rather make my scripts a bit more concise (plus, find out why the above doesn't work aswell as it's genuinely annoying me!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define

```
has_many :pop_vlans
```

which means you must access it with

```
@logical_interface = LogicalInterface.find(...)
@logical_interface.pop_vlans # return an array of pop_vlans
#                          ^

@logical_interface.pop_vlans.map(&:pop_id) # return an array of pop_ids
```